# Cordova not accepting new changes in js file

Tags: android, angular, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am integrating google admob in my app from this link https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-plugin-admob-simple. Problem is when I am building my app after making some changes in the js file. Build first removes the newly created change and then it builds. So in this way, I am not able to write new code for admob in the js file. What will be the solution to this problem?

Comment: You might be using the wrong js file? Might be, that there is a src file and you are editing the build output.

Comment: @Dirk js file is in src folder only. Leave js, if I am editing versionCode and versionName of manifest file then also new change is not reflecting.

Comment: You are probably editing files inside the platform/android folder, which are auto-generated everytime you build the app. You cannot manually edit them, you have to edit the source from the project's plugins folder.